# how to change one element value of specific index of array in firebase uisng flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

i want to change taken value to true on specific index of notification time stamp (array in fire base ,shown in image)so how i write my query
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGWpI.jpg

my code:-

```
await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('Prescriptions')
    .doc(medicineDetails['id'].toString())
    .update({
        'NotificationTimeStamp ': FieldValue.arrayUnion([{}])
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can only add or remove from an array, but as a work around you can do this by changing the array in code the replacing the array in firebase.